# UITableView as subview of MKMapView

Tags: ios

I would add a UITableView under an MKMapView, and make it resizable as the orientation of the device changes. Also, the table should hide/show as per user request.
I succeed in adding the subview, either in IB and in the code, but the problem is that when I change the orienation from portrait to landscape, the table is not properly rendered.

Comment: So the table view is not really a _subview_ of the map view, right?  They're just next to each other?  The table view is not _inside_ the map view, or is it?

Comment: yes, the tableview is just next the mapview, both on the same view. I would show and hide the tableview easily, and almost achieved that. The problem is with landscape resizing...

Answer (score 0):

You can design and use another xib file for landscape mode or use autoresizingMask.